Saving instance of model prior to sending out response in Django
Is there a way to add a record to me DB BEFORE sending off a response? I just learned about Django Signals so I assume that might be a candidate.
The reason why I'm asking this is because of an issue I am having using knox + drfpasswordless.
This snippet is where the authentication token is returned. However, the token is not saved here.
When I call AuthToken.create(), this will save the token to my database but it will cause .is_valid() to return False because my serializer (ModelSerializer) is based off of AuthToken which has digest has a primary key.
class AuthTokenResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = AuthToken
        fields = ["digest", "token_key", "user_id", "created", "expiry"]

The workaround I was thinking of is to create an instance of AuthToken and save if right before sending out a response. If it's not possible, I was considering forking the project ot modify the code

I haven't really used those packages but I feel this question might be lacking a [mre], just a serializer isn't really enough to reproduce your problem. Please [edit] and add a [mre].
